# Ordenar array de objetos por dos propiedades tipo fecha

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Tengo el siguiente arrray de objetos, que quiero ordenar por `fechaFin` (primero la mas actual y después la que no tienen dato) y después por `fechaPublicacion`

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "exp":"1",
        "fechaFin": "",
        "fechaPublicacion": "2022-04-22T07:35:00.003Z"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "exp": "2",
        "fechaFin": "",
        "fechaPublicacion": "2022-04-20T11:57:36.003Z"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "exp": "3",
        "fechaFin": "2022-04-28T12:00:00.003Z",
        "fechaPublicacion": "2022-04-25T11:13:54.003Z"
    }
]
```

El `sort` que tengo es el siguiente, el cual funciona con `FechaFin`, primera condición, pero no con la segunda, `FechaPublicacion`, que no la ordena

```
.sort(
      (a, b) =>
        this.dateFormat(b.fechaFin) - this.dateFormat(a.fechaFin) &&
        this.dateFormat(b.fechaPublicacion) - this.dateFormat(a.fechaPublicacion)
    );
```

Función `dateFormat`

```
dateFormat(date: string) {
    return date != '' ? new Date(date).getTime() : 0;
  }
```

El **objetivo que busco** es que el resultado sea el siguiente, `primero id 3, segundo id 1 y tercero id 2`. *El porque, pues porque el id 3 es el único que tiene fechaFin y luego al entrar en juego la propiedad fechaPublicacion, iría el id 1 (dia 22) y luego el 2 (dia 20)*

Comment: He probado tu código y diria que funciona sin hacer cambios (tan solo poniendolo bien como puedes ver aqui: https://jsfiddle.net/x6aenjho/)

Comment: La cosa es que a mi en cualquier playground me funciona, pero a la hora de meterlo en un proyecto de angular con TS, solo me hace la primera ordenación

Comment: Ah, perdona, no se de angular ni typescript, no me di cuenta de eso. Suerte!

Comment: Bueno, básicamente, angular aquí no hace nada, sería typescript. Aunque el sort lo he hecho en JS y tampoco me lo ordena bien.

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta a mi pregunta, ha sido simplemente **ordenar el array dos veces**. Es decir un primer `sort` con la primera condición y un segundo, con la segunda.

No se que sentido tiene, pero en mi escenario, ha sido la solución